# ZendFramework 2 - ServiceManager in my Class

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I begin to use Zend2 in my work not so long, and my question 
how get  ServiceManager in my class "Blog".
This class  is contain

```
$this->db 
$this->logger 
$this->logger_error
$this->session
$this->filter
$this->access
$this->view 
$this->user 
$this->base_url
```

many fields for work.

I use this class in Controllers and without Controller.
Now I create class

```
class Application extends Zend\Mvc\Application
{

    static public function init()
    {
        return \Zend\Mvc\Application::init(include 'config/application.config.php');
    }
}
```

and use it for initialization

```
class Blog
{
     /**
      *  
      * @var Doctrine\DBAL\Connection 
      */
    protected $db;
    /** 
     *
     * @var Zend\Log\Logger
     */
    protected $logger;
    /** 
     *
     * @var Zend\Log\Logger
     */
    protected $logger_error;
    /**             
     *
     * @var Variable
     */
    protected $variable;
     /**
     *
     * @var \Zend\Cache\Storage\Adapter\Filesystem
     */
    protected $cache;
    /**
     *
     * @var \Zend\Session\Container
     */
    protected $session;

    function __construct()
    {
         $sm = Application::init()->getServiceManager();


        $this->db =  $sm->get('db');
        $this->logger = $sm->get("logger");
        $this->logger_error = $sm->get("logger_error");
        $this->variable = $sm->get("variable");
        $this->cache = $sm->get("cache");
        $this->session = $sm->get("session");
    }
```

Is it normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say this isn't the correct solution.

The correct way to retrieve the service manager is by implementing the interface `Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface` in your class `Blog`.

```
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class Blog implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface {

    protected $serviceLocator;

    public function getServiceLocator() {
        return $this->serviceLocator;
    }

    public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator) {
        $this->serviceLocator = $serviceLocator;
    }

}
```

Then you must retrieve this call through the service manager, like in the controller:

```
$blog = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('namespace\of\Blog');
```

And finally, in the configuration file (`Module.php` or `module.config.php`, you declare your class:

```
// ...
'service_manager' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'namespace\of\Blog' => 'namespace\of\Blog'
    )
),
// ...
```

If you need this class in a place where you don't have access to the service manager, then you are creating this class in the wrong place.
Looking at the different components you are retrieving in your class (database, logs, cache, session), you are doing a lot of stuff in this class. 
I would suggest to split this logic in different classes and instantiate them in the module's boostrap:

```
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

class Module {

    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $event) {
        $serviceManager =$event->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
        $blog = $serviceManager->get('namespace\of\Blog');
    }

}
```

Comment: Problem not in controller, problem in Class  Blog, how get ServiceLocator in Class Blog?       First way - put serviceLocator in __constructor of Class Blog, but for me is very strange after Zend1.

Comment: Problem in constructor of Blog. If I use this class Blog implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface, I cant get serviceLocator in constructor/

Comment: `but for me is very strange after Zend1` -> Zend 1 and Zend 2
Zend 2 are two completely different things. You can't do in Zend 2 everything you did in Zend 1, and viceversa. (Ok, actually some things are not so different..).

Comment: `Problem in constructor of Blog. If I use this class Blog implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface, I cant get serviceLocator in constructor/ `
That's because the service locator is not set in the constructor, but only when the method `setServiceLocator()` is called, and that is done by the invokable factory.
You don't have to instantiate all your variables (db, logger, etc.) on the `Blog` constructor. You should instead create a `getDb()` method, and inside it check if the class variable `db` is already instantiated. If not, you instantiate it and then you return it.

Comment: Take a look at the tutorial: https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/user-guide/database-and-models.html#back-to-the-controller. You should do it this way.
However, I suggest you to look directly to Zend 3, because Zend 2 is deprecated and not supported anymore (since 2018-03-31)

Comment: Ok, but If I need call Class Blog for import in script without MVC, is it possible?          In Zend1 I can do it, because I use Zend_Registry, so it's vary easy in Zend1. But in Zend 2 I can't do it easy without MVC , without getServiceManager. So - I must use Controllers always. It's not easy way)))

Comment: Ok, I decided this. Thanks.